# Using image directory to show image

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to create an e-commerce site which sells PC components using PHP and MySQL.

I'm using a database which has a table called 'components' which stores PC components with fields like 'name', 'type' etc. I have a field called 'image' as I was told it is better to store images in the file system rather than as a BLOB. The field contains the name of the image for that component (e.g. for Intel i7 2700k processor the image filed has inteli72700k/jpg). The image will be stored in '../images/products/'.

Now i'm trying to make my product list (i.e. a user clicked on 'Processors' and I am now trying to show the list of products we have, similar to overclockers.co.uk). I'm creating a table where the table heading is the name of the product and there is one row per product.

```
<table id="products">
            <?php
            //Connects to the DB, localhost is yourpc, root is the username and there is no password
            $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
            //This is the database we want to access in phpMyAdmin
            mysql_select_db('pctweeks');

            $query = "SELECT * FROM component WHERE type = 'CPU'";

            $query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($con));

            if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) >= 1){

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
                echo "<th>{$row['name']}</th>" .
                "<tr><td>{$row['image']}</td></tr>";
            }
            } else
            {
                echo 'No Products';
            }   
        ?>              
        </table>
```

The problem is the `{$row['image']}` part. I know I have to use an image tag but I don't know how to insert the directory of the pictures before the `$row['image']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you use the code like here:

```
echo "<th>{$row['name']}</th>" .
  "<tr><td> <img src='../images/products/{$row['image']}'/> </td></tr>";
```

Comment: This worked, I thought I was close but I wasn't using the single quotations on the path ('../images..'). Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
define( 'IMG_PATH', 'PATH_OF_YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_HERE' );

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    echo "<th>{$row['name']}</th>" .
    "<tr><td><img src='".IMG_PATH."'{$row['image']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Replace "PATH_OF_YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_HERE" with your actual image folder path.

Hope this helps..